# How to use this script to email multiple people without showing all emails in the to field?

Tags: php, email, sharing, verification

I have this script below that i would like to tweak so it can do two things:

1. Send emails to multiple addresses (right now it only works if one email address is being sent an email.
2. In the "to" field it should not display all others who have received the same notification.  So each email should feel individual.

Code:

```
         //Query to get emails
         //$share_to comes from a drop down selection of users.  
         //it could be 1 person or multiple people.
         //The way its stored in the field is this way user1,user2,user3,user4 or if one person then just user1.  

         $sql = "SELECT email_address from accounts 
         WHERE person_id='$share_to'";
         $result = mysql_query($sql);

         $query = mysql_query($sql) or die 
         ("Error: ".mysql_error());

         if ($result == "")
         {
         echo "";
         }
         echo "";


         $rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 


         if($rows == 0)
         {
         print("");

         }
         elseif($rows > 0)
         {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

         {

         $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email_address']);


         print("");
         }

         }


         $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
         $headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";
         $headers .= "BCC: $email\r\n";
         $to = "support@domain.com"; //the mail in the "TO", visible to all. 
         there has to be 1.
         $subject = "$fullname Asked you something";
         $message = "<html><body>";
         $message .= "Hi!, <br><br>$fullname asked you something.<br><br>";
         $message .= "<a href=www.domain.com/login.php>Click here to login.</a><br><br>";
         $message .= "Please reply to this email if you have any questions.<br><br>Thanks,    
         <br><br>Abe<br>";
         $message .= "<img src=www.domain.com/images/logohop.png /><br><br>";

         $message .= "</body></html>";
         mail($to, "Subject: $subject",
         $message, "$headers" );
         echo "";
```

Comment: put the mail sending inside the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Query to get emails
         //$share_to comes from a drop down selection 
         of users.  it could be 1 person or multiple 
         people.The way its stored in the field is 
         this way user1,user2,user3,user4 
         or if one person then just user1.  

         $sql = "SELECT email_address from accounts 
         WHERE person_id='$share_to'";
         $result = mysql_query($sql);

         $query = mysql_query($sql) or die 
         ("Error: ".mysql_error());

         if ($result == "")
         {
         echo "";
         }
         echo "";


         $rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 


         if($rows == 0)
         {
         print("");

         }
         elseif($rows > 0)
         {
         $email='';
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

         {

         $email. = htmlspecialchars($row['email_address']).',';


         print("");
         }

         }


         $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
         $headers .= "From: $usermail\r\n";
         $headers .= "BCC: ".rtrim($email,",")."\r\n";
         $to = "support@domain.com"; //the mail in the "TO", visible to all. 
         there has to be 1.
         $subject = "$fullname Asked you something";
         $message = "<html><body>";
         $message .= "Hi!, <br><br>$fullname asked you something.<br><br>";
         $message .= "<a href=www.domain.com/login.php>Click here to login.</a><br><br>";
         $message .= "Please reply to this email if you have any questions.<br><br>Thanks,    
         <br><br>Abe<br>";
         $message .= "<img src=www.domain.com/images/logohop.png /><br><br>";

         $message .= "</body></html>";
         mail($to, "Subject: $subject",
         $message, "$headers" );
         echo "";
```

Comment: Hey.  Now it doesn't send any emails whatsoever.

Comment: print_r($email) and see the email addresses. Make sure the email address are fetched properly

Comment: If i select one person to send notification to then it works and print:  Array ( [0] => person@domain.com) but if i selected more than 1 person then it wouldn't print it.

Comment: OK now it says: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' and the line is $email. = htmlspecialchars($row['email_address']).',';

Comment: come close the dot $email .= htmlspecialchars($row['email_address']).',';

Comment: Ok.  it gives me the same issue as before.  if one person is selected then it gives me email,(just like that email and then comma).  If i select more than 1 then it gives me blank.

Comment: Any solutions? please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

use any one of these, you can send email to multiple user

```
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

OR

```
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com,birthdayarchive2@example.com ' . "\r\n";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php for help

Use `$headers .= 'BCc: birthdayarchive@example.com,birthdayarchive2@example.com ' . "\r\n";` to invisible other user from your contact

Comment: yes but will this prevent receivers from seeing other receivers?

Comment: use $headers .= 'BCc: birthdayarchive@example.com,birthdayarchive2@example.com ' . "\r\n";

Comment: yeah but then in the to field it shows my email from where its being sent. if i then choose to use $email in the to field then it will show all the email addresses.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want recipients to see the full list, you can either send out multiple emails, one to each recipient - as Dagon mentions above, just move the mail code to inside the loop - or you can use the BCC field.

To send one email to multiple recipients, you need to add a comma separated list of addresses in -

```
$emails = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $emails[] = htmlspecialchars($row['email_address']);
}
```

and then:

`$headers .= "BCC: " . implode(",", $emails) . "\r\n";`

Should do it.

Comment: Its giving me this error, not sure how to fix it: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' and it points to your $headers line.

Comment: @ariel there is an extra dot and missing parenthesis, it should be `$headers .= "BCC: " . implode("," , $emails) . "\r\n";`

Comment: This is what happens when you enter code without testing it first. Thanks, @danishgoel.